# Is there a benefit to breaking up Integration tests with TestCategory?

Tags: .net, testing, integration-testing, mstest

Our solution will eventually be large enterprise, so the number of integration tests will grow (although small right now). We are aiming for a near-continuous deployment (2 days between commit and release).

We have Unit tests in MyProj.Tests.Unit and Integration tests in MyProj.Tests.Integration. We use the TFS cloud continuous integration for Unit tests and a special build that runs up a dummy environment for the integration tests. The split between unit and integration tests is not the problem here, the problem is what the benefits are splitting up integration tests.

For us integration tests are those that require external resources such as the DB or a test web service. We are trying to decide whether to use a TestCategory to mark tests by the resources they need, such as:

```
[TestCategory("NeedsDB")]
```

or

```
[TestCategory("NeedsServiceX")]
```

Our current integration test environment is quick but is not under any great load as we are early on in the project. Some Devs have mentioned that it is useful to see what a method needs by its attributes but I prefer developers to use their eyes and brains rather than relying on attributes that need to be manually updated.

I am trying to decide whether marking up tests in this way is boilerplate [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) or not.

- Am I going to hit problems in the future if I do not partition my integration tests now?
- Are we abusing the TestCategory attribute in this way? Is it meant for something else?

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems with MSTest is that you have to mark each test with a category rather than being able to mark a whole fixture using NUnit for example. I would be skeptical that you would be able to keep the categories up to date in a medium to large project. Wouldn't you be better fixing the problem when it actually crops up in the future, than trying to fix a non existant problem now. When you finaly do have the problem, you'll be in a much better prosition to fix it then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tool allows you to select and run tests by category, it can come in handy as the test suite grows in size and execution time. For instance, you could have a category for tests relevant to the current release, a second called basic core, and another category called regression and then run them at different points and frequencies in your build pipeline.